# Get the element in a JQuery Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting the element in a jQuery Callback function.   I have tried various suggestions of $(this) and $(this.element) with no success.

```
$.fn.onTypeFinished = function (func) {
        $(this).bind("keypress", onKeyPress)
        function onKeyPress() {
            setTimeout(onTimeOut, 500);
        }

        function onTimeOut() {
            func.apply();
        }
        return this;
    };

    $(".user-input").onTypeFinished(function () {
        var ntabindex = parseFloat($(this.element).attr('tabindex'));
        ntabindex++;
        $('input[tabindex=' + ntabindex + ']').focus();
    });
```

I have been thinking I need some way to pass a reference to this to the callback function but no other similar posts seem to suggest that route.

Here is a JSFiddle of what I am trying to do.  The gist of the functionality is I'm trying to auto advance to the next input according to tabindex.

http://jsfiddle.net/helfon/fdu8xw0h/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it looks like you want to pass the element on which the keypress has occurred as `this` to the callback.

For that to happen you need to pass the correct context to the `timeout` handler, for which we can use .bind() as shown below.

Also to make the timer work correctly some other corrections are also made.

```js
$.fn.onTypeFinished = function(func) {
  $(this).bind("keypress", onKeyPress)

  function onKeyPress() {
    var onTypeFinished = $(this).data('onTypeFinished');
    if (!onTypeFinished) {
      onTypeFinished = {};
      $(this).data('onTypeFinished', onTypeFinished);
    }

    clearTimeout(onTypeFinished.keytimer);
    onTypeFinished.keytimer = setTimeout(onTimeOut.bind(this), 500);
  }

  function onTimeOut() {
    func.apply(this);
  }
  return this;
};

$(".user-input").onTypeFinished(function() {
  //$('input[tabindex=3]').focus();
  var ntabindex = parseFloat(this.getAttribute('tabindex'));
  ntabindex++;
  $('input[tabindex=' + ntabindex + ']').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="1" tabindex=1 class="user-input">
<input id="2" tabindex=2 class="user-input">
<input id="3" tabindex=3 class="user-input">
<input id="4" tabindex=4 class="user-input">
```

Comment: I see... it did not seem to be working at the time i've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the logs, it seems that your `this` keyword inside the jQuery fn is pointing to the window object instead, I've bound the functions as follows and passed `this` in your `apply`, and got it working so that `this` points to the input elements instead:

```
    $.fn.onTypeFinished = function (func) {
        var time;
        $(this).each(function () {
            $(this).on('keypress', onKeyPress);
        });

        function onKeyPress() {
            clearTimeout(time);
            time = setTimeout(onTimeOut.bind(this), 500);
        }

        function onTimeOut() {
            func.apply(this);
        }
        return this;
    };
    $(".user-input").onTypeFinished(function () {
        //$('input[tabindex=3]').focus();
        var ntabindex = parseFloat($(this).attr('tabindex'));
        ++ntabindex;
        $('input[tabindex=' + ntabindex + ']').focus();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fdu8xw0h/9/

You have to also iterate over the array of elements as your selector is returning an array of inputs, so you have to handle them separately, otherwise your event will occur only once, i've tested it and it goes from the first input to the second and then it stops working. With the approach i've pasted here it will go from input to input.

Answer (score -1):

You should understand that `this` changes whenever you change scope. Always `var $this = $(this)` to lock it down.

```
 $.fn.onTypeFinished = function (func) {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.bind("keypress", onKeyPress);
      function onKeyPress() {
            setTimeout(onTimeOut, 500);
      }

      function onTimeOut() {
            func($this); //I would personally send this, like how you do $.each(function(count, element){})
      }
      return this;
  };

  $(".user-input").onTypeFinished(function (t) {
      var ntabindex = parseInt($(t).attr('tabindex')) + 1; //You should parse int here
      $('input[tabindex=' + ntabindex + ']').focus();
});
```

### Of course, you can simplify the above more into:

```
 $.fn.onTypeFinished = function (func) {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.bind("keypress", onKeyPress);
      function onKeyPress() {
          setTimeout(function(){
              func($this);
          }, 500);
      }
      return this;
};

$(".user-input").onTypeFinished(function (t) {
      $('input[tabindex=' + String(parseInt($(t).attr('tabindex')) + 1) + ']').focus();
});
```

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vimxts/fdu8xw0h/6/

Comment: It's a step in the correct direction, but it needs to also determine which input is actually the focused element within scope.

It also literally only executes once. Then it stops working entirely because of the unbind.